# azure webjob python error: could not create 'D:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests': Access is denied

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to install requests from my requirements.txt file on **Azure**.

When I run:

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

I get the error:

> could not create 'D:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests': Access is denied

In my Azure webapp I have installed the following python extension:

```
Python 3.6.1 x64 3.6.1.3
```

So I am presuming that I need the 'requests' package to install to here:

D:\home\python361x64\Lib\site-packages\ instead of 'D:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\

Any ideas how I can fix this ?

Comment: did you try with sudo: `sudo python.exe -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Hi,  Got it working by creating a run.cmd file & then specifying the python path to run python.exe from eg. D:\home\python361x64\python.exe get_stats.py

Comment: And running python.exe -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt from the version path eg D:\home\python361x64\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt

Comment: @PeteStilgoe - you should then post a proper answer with your solution, vs posting comments. This way, the question can be closed out properly.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by creating a run.cmd file & then specifying the python path to run python.exe from eg. D:\home\python361x64\python.exe get_stats.py – Pete Stilgoe yesterday

And running python.exe -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt from the version path eg D:\home\python361x64\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt – Pete Stilgoe yesterday